# Unable to debug a nodejs express app in vs code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I'm encountering an issue while debugging a specific Node.js application, despite having identical configurations across multiple apps. Here's the configuration I'm using:

```json
// nodemon.json
{
  "restartable": "rs",
  "ignore": [".git", "node_modules/", "dist/", "coverage/"],
  "watch": ["lib/", ".env", "@types/"],
  "execMap": {
    "ts": "node -r ts-node/register"
  },
  "env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development"
  },
  "ext": "js,json,ts"
}
```

script used to execute

```json
"start:dev": "nodemon --config nodemon.json lib/server.ts | bunyan"
```

server.ts

```
// Disable eslint on this file to prevent imports from being re-orderd. dotenv config needs to be first.
/* eslint-disable */
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

import app from './app';
import { startWorkers } from './services/workers';
import { emitEvent } from 'services/events';
import { AddressInfo } from 'net';
const logger = require('/services/logger');

process.on('uncaughtException', async (err) => {
  logger.error({ err }, 'An unhandled exception was thrown, and will cause the application to restart');
  const logCtx = {};
  const payload = {};
  try {
    await emitEvent('error.unhandled', { err, logCtx, payload });
  } catch (ex) {
    logger.error({ err: ex }, 'Failed to emit the unhandled exception');
  }
  process.exit(1);
});
startWorkers();
if (process.env.WORKER_MODE !== 'ON') {
  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
  const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    const port = (server.address() as AddressInfo).port;
    logger.info(`Express server listening on port ${port}`);
  });
}
```

Despite seeing the message "Express server listening on port 8083," indicating that the server is running fine, I'm unable to debug the application. Breakpoints don't seem to be working regardless of their placement.

I've attempted several troubleshooting steps, including reinstalling node_modules, restarting both the IDE and my laptop, and updating Visual Studio Code, but the issue persists. Notably, I've observed that the call stack of the debugger isn't connected to the code being executed.

What could potentially be causing this peculiar issue where debugging works in all applications except for this particular one?

Comment: share your vscode `launch.json`. It is vital for vscode-debugging, but it seems your are not using that instead using nodemon which don't allow you to put break a point